# Angular JS: How to use ng-repeat for complex objet

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a complex object coming from the web service as shown below, how to display PatientId and description, if anyone have any good idea, please help me thru it.:

```
 $scope.myData = {"PatientSearchResponse": {
"pageNumber": 1,
"pageSize": 50,
"patDataBean": [
  {
    "gender": {
      "code": "male",
      "description": "Male",
      "type": "gender"
    },
    "patDateofBirth": "1997/06/19",
    "patFirstName": "aman",
    "patLastName": "elvis",
    "patSurvivalStat": {
      "code": "A",
      "description": "Alive",
      "type": "patient_status"
    },
    "patientIdentifier": {
      "OID": "589a9cf6-4513-49e1-bd5c-c7363849ed93",
      "organizationId": {
        "PK": 54,
        "siteName": "CTRP"
      },
      "patientId": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "gender": {
      "code": "male",
      "description": "Male",
      "type": "gender"
    },
    "patDateofBirth": "2001/07/18",
    "patFirstName": "Elvis",
    "patLastName": "Harvey",
    "patSurvivalStat": {
      "code": "dead",
      "description": "Dead",
      "type": "patient_status"
    },
    "patientIdentifier": {
      "OID": "151d0222-3726-40ee-8f69-0a6800727607",
      "organizationId": {
        "OID": "83d09227-9c65-4d7b-94da-baaf5c07b38a",
        "siteName": "Texas"
      },
      "patientId": "100"
    }
  }]}}
```

In my HTML I am using ng-repeat as:

```
<td ng-repeat="(key, value) in grid.columns">
                            <div>
                                <p >{{row[key]}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

my JS file as:

```
myDataContainer = $scope.myData.PatientSearchResponse.patDataBean;
$scope.grid.columns = {patientIdentifier: "Patient Id",patFirstName: "First Name",patLastName: "Last Name",patDateofBirth: "Date of Birth",patSurvivalStat: "Description"};
angular.forEach(myDataContainer, function (values, index) {
                        $scope.grid.rows.push(values);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you can just do this :

```
<td ng-repeat="pat in myData.PatientSearchResponse.patDataBean">
                            {{pat.patientIdentifier}} - {{pat.patSurvivalStat.description}}
                        </td>
```

Comment: I want to make it dynamic so that it can display any different object with different parameters. I know how to hard code HTML to make it working. I just want to make it dynamic in the way I don't have to change HTML part for any other object. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Would be more practical to make `columns` an array of objects with standardized keys

```
$scope.grid.columns = [
    {property : 'patientIdentifier', heading : "Patient Id"},
    {property : 'patFirstName', heading : "First Name"},
    {property : 'patLastName', heading : "Last Name"},
    {property : 'patDateofBirth', heading : "Date of Birth"},
    {property : 'patSurvivalStat', heading : "Description"}
]
```

Then use those to  set both headings and content

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="col in grid.columns">{{::col.heading}}</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in myData.patDataBean">
        <td ng-repeat="col in grid.columns">{{::item[col.property]}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to make it dynamic so that it can display any different object with different parameters. I know how to hard code HTML to make it working. I just want to make it dynamic in the way I don't have to change HTML part for any other object. Thanks for trying.

Comment: What hard code html are you talking about? How much more dynamic can it be than what is shown here?

Comment: Just change columns config to use a different object schema. Also note that there was no mention in question of being able to switch objects

Comment: Thank for your valuable answer. yeah, my bad, I had to mention about switching objects. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well there is no way to do that without a schema

Comment: Hi, I just got success in doing it by iterating inside object then putting those key-value back into the main object(basically modifying it). Only problem now I am facing is not able to add all keys into the main object as some of the keys have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this man:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) { 

$scope.myData = {"PatientSearchResponse": {
"pageNumber": 1,
"pageSize": 50,
"patDataBean": [
  {
    "gender": {
      "code": "male",
      "description": "Male",
      "type": "gender"
    },
    "patDateofBirth": "1997/06/19",
    "patFirstName": "aman",
    "patLastName": "elvis",
    "patSurvivalStat": {
      "code": "A",
      "description": "Alive",
      "type": "patient_status"
    },
    "patientIdentifier": {
      "OID": "589a9cf6-4513-49e1-bd5c-c7363849ed93",
      "organizationId": {
        "PK": 54,
        "siteName": "CTRP"
      },
      "patientId": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "gender": {
      "code": "male",
      "description": "Male",
      "type": "gender"
    },
    "patDateofBirth": "2001/07/18",
    "patFirstName": "Elvis",
    "patLastName": "Harvey",
    "patSurvivalStat": {
      "code": "dead",
      "description": "Dead",
      "type": "patient_status"
    },
    "patientIdentifier": {
      "OID": "151d0222-3726-40ee-8f69-0a6800727607",
      "organizationId": {
        "OID": "83d09227-9c65-4d7b-94da-baaf5c07b38a",
        "siteName": "Texas"
      },
      "patientId": "100"
    }
  }]}}

}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Controller">
  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    
    
    <tr ng-repeat="m in myData.PatientSearchResponse.patDataBean">
      <td>{{m.patientIdentifier.patientId}}</td>
      <td>{{m.patSurvivalStat.description}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</body>
</html>
```